# How to retrieve last node using XPath in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have following part of xml file.

```
<UN N="@U1">
    <DT N="24/06/2011">
        <PN N="@P1">
            <TM N="02:24:11">
                <JB T="GP">
                    <A>notepad</A>
                    <Z>Notepad</Z>
                    <N>Untitled - Notepad</N>
                    <J>1;0;1;1;0;0</J>
                    <C>0.00500;0.09500;0.03500</C>
                    <S>1;0;1;1</S>
                    <P>0;0</P>
                    <F>0</F>
                </JB>
            </TM>
        </PN>
    </DT>

    <DT N="23/06/2011">
        <PN N="@P1">
            <TM N="02:38:49">
                <JB T="PAGP">
                    <A>notepad</A>
                    <Z>Notepad</Z>
                    <N>Untitled - Notepad</N>
                    <J>1;1;1;1;0;1</J>
                    <C>0.00500;0.09500;0.03500</C>
                    <S>1;1;0;0</S>
                    <P>1;1</P>
                    <F>0</F>
                </JB>
            </TM>               
        </PN>
    </DT>

    .....
    .....

</UN>
```

I need to get the last node where PN N=@P1.

Sample query will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for a `<DT>` or `<PN>` node to be found?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `last()` XPath function can be used to find the last of a node set. So the last `<PN>` node with attribyte `N` having a value `@P1` would be:

```
//PN[@N='@P1'][position() = last()]
```

The .NET code will depend on which XML API you're using: [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx), [`XPathDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathdocument.aspx) or LINQ to XML ([`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)). (The approach with [`XmlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) would be to load into one of the three and then use that.)

*Edit (based on comment)* To return the `<F>` descendant of the last `<PN>` with attribute as above, where `xDoc` is an instance of `XmlDocument`:

```cs
var foundNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//PN[@N='@P1'][position() = last()]/TM/JB/F");
```

*Edit #2 (based on another comment)*: To return the *last* `<PN>` where each `<DT>` can contain multiple `<DT>` elements<sup>1</sup> across all the `<DT>` elements.

Testing this with some better sample XML (see below), using [`XmlElement.SelectNodes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.selectnodes.aspx) and then iterating over the returned node set showed that the right node was being found, it just wasn't the first and therefore not returned by `SelectSingleNode`. This is the clue: the `last()` predicate was being applied within each `//PN[@N='@P1']` matching. A quick change of precedence was all that was needed:

```
(//PN[@N='@P1'])[last()]
```

---

<sup>1</sup> For future reference, if multiple elements are possible, then show at least two in the sample, otherwise readers will assume only singular instances. Also strip out all nodes (like children) not needed:

The sample XML I used for testing (added x attributes to make it easy to identify the element selected while testing):

```xml
<UN N='@U1'>
  <DT N='24/06/2011'>
    <PN N='@P1' x='#1'/>
    <PN N='@P1' x='#2'/>
    <PN N='@P2' x='#3'/>
  </DT>

  <DT N='24/06/2011'>
    <PN N='@P1' x='#4'/>
    <PN N='@P1' x='#5'/>
    <PN N='@P2' x='#6'/>
  </DT>

  <DT N='24/06/2011'>
    <PN N='@P3' x='#7'/>
    <PN N='@P4' x='#8'/>
    <PN N='@P5' x='#9'/>
  </DT>
</UN>
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working superbly. What if I want to retrieve last node of TM/JB/F from the returned node.  I am using XmlDocument class.

Comment: I found myself. it will be like this: '@"//PN[@N='@P1'][position() = last()]/TM[position() = last()]/JB/F";' Any how thanks for initial XPath.

Comment: Sorry late comment. It return first DT's last PN node, but I need last node irrespective of DT in .xml file. Note: .xml file can contain any number of DT and inside DT it contain many number of PN.

Comment: @Syed: I'll have a look later, but a better xml sample would help (please update the Q). Remove details (eg. child nodes irrelevant to the Q).

Comment: @Syed: Updated... I think this has it.

Answer (score 6):

The XPath operation:

```
"/UN/DT[PN/@N='@p1'][last()]"
```

will return the last **DT** node for which `PN=@p1`.